# How to change ComboBox items to Tabs in Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I am following a tutorial to create a simple Power BI embedded WPF app where I can access and view some shared Dashboards and reports in the app.

Currently, the layout is such that when I click on the "Dashboards" Radio button, I can click to expand its drop down menu and view all of the dashboards I have access to in my Power BI account. But I wanted to know if there is a way where I can have the list of dashboards show up as clickable tabs when I click on to view all of my Dashboards available?

[image]

And I want to be able to do something like the picture below, where when I click on "Shirts", it expands to different types of shirts available and I can click on either "Casual, Dressed, or Denim" and view those specific types of shirts. In my case, it would be "Dashboards" instead of Shirts, and when expanded, I can click on any of my available dashboards and view them.

[image]

I am using the ComboBox option inside of a StackPanel and I am trying to figure out if there is another option to dynamically show my list of dashboards in a vertical clickable tabs instead of using a drop down option?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
   <Label Margin="5,5" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Dashboards</Label>
   <ComboBox x:Name="appWorkSpacesDashboardList" Margin="5" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="appWorkSpacesDashboardList_SelectionChanged" />
   <RadioButton x:Name="DashboardSelected"  GroupName="PBIRenderSelect" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True"></RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

And I have the appWorkSpacesDashboardList method as:

```
if (DashboardSelected.IsChecked.Value && appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem != null)
{
  embed = (PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesDashboardList.SelectedItem;
  parameters = new object[] { embed.EmbeddedUrl, Token, embed.EmbeddedId, PBIObjectType.Dashboard, 0, string.Empty };
  PBIEmbeddedWB.InvokeScript("LoadEmbeddedObject", parameters);
}
else if (ReportSelected.IsChecked.Value && appWorkSpacesReportList.SelectedItem != null)
{
  embed = (PBIContentObject)appWorkSpacesReportList.SelectedItem;
  parameters = new object[] { embed.EmbeddedUrl, Token, embed.EmbeddedId, PBIObjectType.Report, 0, string.Empty };
  PBIEmbeddedWB.InvokeScript("LoadEmbeddedObject", parameters);
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but have you looked at a ```ListBox```?

Comment: it is unclear what you want. try `ItemsControl` and its derivatives like `ListBox`. and forget about reusing the same instance of a control if that's what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear of what I really want to be able to implement. I have added a sample screenshot of how I want the list of items to be displayed. Instead of a dropdown menu, I want the list of dashboard items to be like clickable tabs/buttons/links which shows up upon expanding "Dashboards".